# How do I remove the Tomcat INFO just from log file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, log4jdbc

How I can remove all my Tomcat INFO from my log file, but just from my log file, I want to see that INFO only in console output

Comment: share log4j current config and whats correct name of **my log file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do. Hope it helps

# Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

```
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

---

```
<!-- Redirect the logging to console. -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
<!-- 
Redirect the logging to a file.. -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
       <param name="append" value="false" />
       <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
       <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
       <!-- For Tomcat -->
       <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myStruts1App.log" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: if you can see I already have that configuration and I sell see the info

Comment: If this works for you please mark this as correct and applied answer